# Why is this question closed? I am finding no satisfactory answers from the personal comment

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, close-reasons

I have a question about my Physics Stack Exchange post:  [Can time dilation be used to prove that relativistic mass does not really increase at speeds near $c$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/708152/)

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* There are [almost 200 SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name) and there are large variations in the speed and aggressiveness of quick-closure. At 70+ questions per day and [over 11,000 existing questions tagged special-relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-relativity) it's pretty common for first questions on this topic to stay open. As the answer points out, unless you can differentiate your question from the linked ones (e.g. I've read these answers and they don't address X) it will stay closed here in Physics SE.

Answer (score 7):

You should see two other questions linked at the top, where it says it's a duplicate:

[image]

If you think your question is really different from these other questions discussing relativistic mass, please *edit* it to explain why the answers to these other questions don't answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

You've chosen not to respond to clarifying questions about how you're defining relativistic mass.  This makes it entirely unclear what you're asking, and is sufficient reason to close the question regardless of whether there are any duplicates out there.